# Discord bot Repeating welcome messages

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot and when I put some codes the bot executes it more than once. For example I put this welcome code to new users and the bot sends the welcome photo 4 times.
Code:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    
    let wChan = "Channel_ID"
    
    if(wChan == null) return;
    
    if(!wChan) return;
    
let font = await jimp.loadFont(jimp.FONT_SANS_64_BLACK) //We declare a 32px font
  let font64 = await jimp.loadFont(jimp.FONT_SANS_64_WHITE)//We declare a 64px font
  let font64b = await jimp.loadFont(jimp.FONT_SANS_64_WHITE)
  let bfont64 = await jimp.loadFont(jimp.FONT_SANS_64_BLACK)
  let mask = await jimp.read('https://i.imgur.com/552kzaW.png') //We load a mask for the avatar, so we can make it a circle instead of a shape
  let welcome = await jimp.read('http://rovettidesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/clouds2.jpg') //We load the base image
  jimp.read(member.user.displayAvatarURL).then(avatar => { //We take the user's avatar
    avatar.resize(200, 200) //Resize it
    mask.resize(200, 200) //Resize the mask
    avatar.mask(mask) //Make the avatar circle
    welcome.resize(1000, 300)
    
  welcome.print(font64, 265, 35, `Bienvenido ${member.user.username} a`) //We print the new user's name with the 64px font
  welcome.print(bfont64, 265, 105, ` ${member.guild.name}`)
  welcome.print(font64, 265, 175, `Gracias a ti ya somos `)
  welcome.print(font64b, 265, 230, `${member.guild.memberCount} usuarios`)
  welcome.composite(avatar, 40, 45).write('Welcome2.png') //Put the avatar on the image and create the Welcome2.png bot
    try{
  member.guild.channels.get(wChan).send(``, { files: ["Welcome2.png"] }) //Send the image to the channel
  }catch(e){
      // dont do anything if error occurs
      // if this occurs bot probably can't send images or messages
  }
  })
});
```

The error it gives me is this:

```
(node:7963) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 6 guildMemberAdd listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I have put in the code some `process.setMaxListeners (1);` but it does not work

Comment: [Java to Javascript is like ham to hamster](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Comment: It seems like the code you provided is been executed 6 times (from the error message), adding 6 listeners to the `guildMemberAdd` event on `bot`.

Comment: If that is. How do I solve it?

Comment: You should move the event inside of your main file, and not in a file / event that is called many times

Comment: I was already in the main part

Comment: @Kktua then we might need a more global look over your code